# Listing Tweets from a protected account?

Tags: php, twitter

I have a protected twitter account but I want to be able to show a list of my most recent tweets on my website.

I'm prepared to dive in to the twitter docs but I just wanted a heads up to know if its possible?

Would my script have to autenticate with my account or is there a way to allow access to my twitter account from a particular IP?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, definitely possible. I don't know if there is a simpler solution, but one way would be to create a new app on Twitter which your account authorizes. In the authorization process, Twitter will give you access tokens for your specific account. Store your access tokens in a database. Read your tweets from a PHP widget say, which uses the Twitter PHP API, and uses your access tokens to display it.

When you are retrieving your tweets, it doesn't matter if it is protected or not as long as you have authorized that specific application.

Simply put, the widget that displays your tweets is a Twitter application that you have authorized. (one-time authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't think so you can read anything from Protected account.

I was reading few articles about the same issue and here is the alternative solution if you would like to give a try. (I personally didn't tried it so leaving up to you to give shot)

http://www.ehow.com/how_6474863_protected-twitter-updates.html